# Cut string of numbers at letter in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cut

I have a string such as `plantford1775.274.284b63.11`.

I have been using `identity=$( echo "$identity" | cut -d'.' -f3)` to cut at each dot, and then choose the third section. I am left with `284b63`.

The format of this part is always a letter, sandwiched by varying amounts of numbers. I would like to take the first few numbers before the letter. An example code line would be this:

```
identity=$( echo "$identity" | cut -d'anyletter' -f1)
```

What do I replace `anyletter` with to cut at whatever letter is listed there, so that I end with a string of `284`?

Answer (score 5):

This could be done in single `awk`, please try following written and tested with your shown samples.

```
echo "$identity" | awk -F'.' '{sub(/[^0-9].*/,"",$3);print $3}'
```

***Explanation:*** simple explanation would be, passing `echo` command's output as a standard input to `awk` code. In `awk` program, setting field separator as `.` for values. Then in 3rd field substituting(using `sub` function of `awk`) everything apart from digits with NULL in 3rd field, then printing it.

Comment: You as well. Good solution.

Comment: This will print out `28463`, which is not the expected output. Perhaps you meant `sub(/[^0-9].*/,"",$3)`, rather than `gsub(/[^0-9]*/,"",$3)`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin, Thanks for very good catch, I have edited my code now, I was writing(mentioning) in explanation sub but somehow written gsub in script, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo plantford1775.274.284b63.11 | cut -d. -f3 | sed 's/[a-z].*//'
```

Comment: Solution ended up being this, but for other reasons I had to remove the -d argument and use this line for 284b63 only.

`identity=$( echo "$identity" | cut  -f3 | sed 's/[a-z].*//')`

Answer (score 2):

Or a slight variation on the REGEX, with `[[...]]` in bash:

```sh
v="plantford1775.274.284b63.11"
[[ $v =~ ^[^.]+.[^.]+.([^.]+).*$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

**Output**

```
284b63
```

Or if you are only interested in the digits before the letter:

```sh
[[ $v =~ ^[^.]+.[^.]+.([[:digit:]]+)[^.]+.*$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

**Output**

```
284
```

Answer (score 2):

With `bash`, using the `=~` operator :

```
[[ $identity =~ [^.]*.[^.]*.([0-9]+) ]] && identity=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

or, in POSIX shell:

```
identity=${identity#*.*.}
identity=${identity%%[^0-9]*}
```

or, using `sed`:

```
identity=$(sed 's/[^.]*.[^.]*.\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' <<< "$identity")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a bash regex and get the result from `$BASH_REMATCH`.

```sh
[[ "$identity" =~ ([0-9]+)[a-z][0-9]+ ]] && identity="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Say we have

```
 identity=284b63
```

then you can do a

```
 lead=${identity%[a-z]*}
```

to set `lead` to 284. Feel free to adapt the pattern to upper case letters and/or other separators.

Answer (score 0):

If *the format of this part is always a letter, sandwiched by varying amounts of numbers*, and you want to match this format, you might also use `gnu awk`, setting the field separator to `.` and use a pattern with a capture group for the 3rd field.

The pattern captures 1 or more digits from the start of the string, and match one of more chars [a-z] after it followed by a digit.

```
echo "$identity" | awk -F'.' 'match($3, /^([0-9]+)[a-z]+[0-9]/, ary) {print ary[1]}'
```

Output

```
284
```

Or using sed with a pattern matching the first 2 dots and the capture group after the 2nd dot:

```
identity=$(sed 's/^[^.]\+\.[^\.]\+\.\([0-9]\+\)[a-z]\+[0-9].*/\1/' <<< "$identity")
```